# post/page content

Tags: posts, pages, shortcode, code

I am trying to insert a post/page into one of my themes files and it won't display shortcodes or PHP.

I have created a page called home in the wordpress admin-paned and inserted into my code the following:

```
<div id="home_page"> <!-- echos the content from the page "home" id:43 -->
            <?php $home_id = 43;
            $home_page = get_page( $home_id );
            ?>  
            <?php echo $home_page->post_content; ?>
    </div> <!-- end #home_page -->
```

and non of the shortcodes that I have in the page work.
I installed a `php in post or page` and tried using php and it doesn't work.

when I insert

```
echo do_shortcode('[youtube_sc url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db3XGpt6nNU]');
```

directly into the code it works.

does anyone know y this happens?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the filter `the_content` e.g.:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$home_page->post_content); ?>
```

Also, you don't need custom shortcodes for youtube, just put the URL in the content (but not a hyperlink), and it'll be swapped out for a youtube player at runtime. No plugins or extra code needed thanks to oembed.